# Using variable/placeholder in the template literal GROQ queries - @nuxtjs/sanity

Tags: nuxt.js, template-literals, sanity

I need a reusable Nuxt component that fetches some data from [Sanity.io](https://www.sanity.io). I'm using the [@nuxtjs/sanity](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/) package, so the query looks like this:

```
import { groq } from '@nuxtjs/sanity'

const query = groq`*[_type == "article"][0].title`

export default {
  async fetch() {
    const result = await this.$sanity.fetch(query)
    this.title = result
  },
  data: () => ({ title: '' }),
}
```

But if I try to use a variable as a placeholder inside the query template literal as is recommended (${placeholder}) it wouldn't work.

This doesn't work:

```
const placeholder = 'article'
const query = groq`*[_type == ${placeholder}][0].title`
```

**EDIT**

In the [Github repository example](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sanity-module/blob/main/example/pages/movie/_slug.vue) of the Sanity module, they use this code to achieve what I was looking for:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { groq } from '@nuxtjs/sanity'

const query = groq`*[_type == "movie" && slug.current == $slug][0] {
  title,
  releaseDate,
  castMembers[] {
    characterName
  },
  overview
}`

interface QueryResult {
  title: string
  releaseDate: string
  castMembers: Array<{ characterName: string }>
  overview: any[]
}

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
    LocalSanityImage: SanityImage,
  },
  async fetch () {
    const movieDetails = await this.$sanity.another.fetch<QueryResult>(query, {
      slug: this.$route.params.slug,
    })
    this.details = movieDetails
  },
  data: () => ({ details: null as null | QueryResult }),
})
```

It's a shame that those solutions don't appear in the [documentation](https://sanity.nuxtjs.org/usage).

Why they are importing Vue? Do those params work with the code example in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Daniel Roe](https://twitter.com/danielcroe) for the help. For the placeholder to be read as a variable, it must be quoted, like this:

```
const placeholder = 'article'
const query = groq`*[_type == "${placeholder}"][0].title`
```